# Gigabit NIC with TCP offload and open driver

Tags: linux, networking, tcp-offload-engine

I'm looking for a gigabit Ethernet adapter with a TCP offload engine that will work nicely with a modern Linux kernel. Due to the way patches and updates are handled, I *really* need one that has an open (blob-less) driver.

I'm beginning to think such a thing might not exist. I'm hoping that I'm just missing a lesser known manufacturer that I could try. I'd rather put up with a relatively quirky card than have to deal with [the issues surrounding closed source TOE drivers](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/toe) in Linux.

I'm aware of the venerable Broadcom and Intel team cards, but I don't want to buy yet another piece of hardware that requires dealing with non-free firmware or driver blobs. I'm so close to getting rid of anything that won't work without them, I'd hate to introduce something else.

I'd also appreciate any 'home brew' experiences, if they relate to this question.

Comment: Regarding your link - why are you needing TOE at all?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the linux networking maintainers [dislike of TOE](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/toe), I'd be surprised if such a thing exists.

Comment: Funny, we both used the same link :)

Comment: Hah! Sorry about that.